# ActivityUnitTestCase and startActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing

In the JavaDoc of [ActivityUnitTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.lang.Object%29) it says:

> Do not call from your setUp() method. You must call this method from each of your test methods.

Isn't putting something in every test method equivalent to putting it in `setUp`, considering that the whole idea behind that method is to do just that, i.e. executing something before every test?

Also, why are we not allowed to do that? I tried it, and it works just fine.

Comment: in a correctly tuned test rig, yes; any code that you could test - including assertions you need rated - can refactor in and out of setUp freely. In an Android test rig, however...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that setUp runs with the test project's class loader, while the actual test methods run with the app under test's class loader. See, for example, this discussion on the RoboGuice mailing list:

http://groups.google.com/group/roboguice/browse_thread/thread/2e129f87ead10b10

Why this is the case, I'm not sure (it seems like a very strange design decision to me). But the upshot is that you can't access anything in the app under test in your setUp method. Which moves setUp into chocolate teapot territory.

Note that this restriction does not apply if you're testing a library project as described here:

http://www.paulbutcher.com/2010/09/android-library-project-with-tests-step-by-step/

Because in that case the tests and the code under test are all in a single app.

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the fact that startActivity runs the Activity's onCreate method on the current (instrumentation) thread, rather than switching it to the UI thread: http://google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/test-runner/src/android/test/ActivityUnitTestCase.java&l=103. If you annotate your test methods with @UiThreadTest, then they'll run in the UI thread, but setUp won't, which could explain the instruction.

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason that they say that is more of a "best practice" than a hard and fast technical reason (note: I could be wrong about that).  The reason is that if each individual test method is essentially self-contained it is easier to create different test suites that will perform the EXACT tests that you need as opposed to running every test in the ActivityTestCase on setUp().